# what offences can the governer pardon in India?

Tags: india

Article 161 of the constitution states

> The Governor of a State shall have the power to grant pardons, reprieves, respites or remissions of punishment or to suspend, remit or commute the sentence of any person convicted of any offence against any law relating to a matter to which the executive power of the State extends

there are 3 lists relating to laws in India.

the Union list , state list and concurrent list

the third is the one where both the state and the union can make laws.

but let's say a law was passed by the union under the concurrent list , can the governer pardon those if the law wasn't passed by the state legislatures